# (Python) How to decode aes.encrypt encoded cipher texts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am making an encyrption program with **Python 3.7.9** and I started learning **pycryptodome** library and AES encryption but when I encrypt a plain text it gives me this: `b'Q\xd7\x05\x0e\xa0\xea\x06b\xefVt'` and I cannot decode it to string. When I try to decode it with `cipher.decode('utf-8')` it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ymzym/OneDrive/Python Projects/Encrypt'n'Decrypt/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    print("Encrypted text:",cipher.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 1: invalid start byte
```

And when I try to decode it with `cipher.decode('latin-1')` it outputs a weird thing: `8ê{ÊÚ´ã`. How can I decode this?

Here is my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter
from Crypto import Random
import base64, os, binascii

def encrypt(key, plaintext):
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16) 
    ctr = Counter.new(AES.block_size * 8, initial_value=iv_int)
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
    ciphertext = aes.encrypt(plaintext)
    return ciphertext

key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(os.urandom(22)) #Creates a 32 bytes AES-256 key
cipher = encrypt(key, b"Hello world")
print("Encrypted text:",cipher.decode('latin-1'))
```

Comment: Encryption in general is working on byte-basis so the output (ciphertext) is a byte array that will contain a lot of bytes that are   not printable (think of x00). If you need a string for storage or transport you should encode the data in Base64 encoding.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I am not expert in encrypting, I am also new to Python. I copied this code from a source and modified a little bit. So I don't understand how can I change encoding to Base64. Can you explain? Also yes, I have to display cipher text in a box with GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Base64 encoding and decoding I'm using this two functions:

```
import base64

def base64Encoding(input):
  dataBase64 = base64.b64encode(input)
  dataBase64P = dataBase64.decode("UTF-8")
  return dataBase64P

def base64Decoding(input):
    return base64.decodebytes(input.encode("ascii"))
```

so on encryption side the code would be:

```
ciphertext = base64Encoding(aes.encrypt(plaintext))
```

On decryption side you decode like this

```
ciphertext = base64Decoding(receivedCiphertext)
```